# I'd like to use VS 2010 Pro on 4 workstations, what MSDN Subscription or licensing model is best?

Tags: visual-studio, msdn

I'd be the only one using the product, but I'll need to install VS on 4 different computers: My office Desktop, one virtual machine, my home desktop and my laptop.

I've been using the MSDN Operating Systems subscription for a number of years so I have a general idea of what I'm allowed to do, but I don't understand if a `Visual Studio Professional with MSDN` allows me to install multiple copies of VS Pro.

To give you an idea of what I'm looking for, I'm currently using `Delphi 2010 Named User`: this allows me to install Delphi on multiple computers, given I'm the only one using those Delphi installations.

Comment: To those tempted to vote for closing: It's related to licensing a development tool. The "licensing" tag contains 1423 question. The "msdn" tag 202 and the "msdnsubscriptions" 31: MSDN is all about licensing, so there's interest in the issue. Besides, the MSDN site doesn't give clear information on the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The license is *per-user*, so you can install it on any number of devices, but it is licensed only for you to use. This is printed in clear text in the [Visual Studio 2010 and MSDN Licensing White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2b1504e6-0bf1-46da-be0e-85cc792c6b9d):

> Any team member can install and use
>   MSDN software on as many devices as
>   they like. The license does not
>   restrict where the device is located
>   (at work, at home, at school, at a
>   customer’s office, etc.). However,
>   each user of that MSDN software must
>   have an appropriate MSDN subscription.

Comment: Thank you, the answer is spot-on, and the link is grate. I understand the licensing model as I've been using MSDN Operating Systems. If the product was named "MSDN with Visual Studio" and not "Visual Studio with MSDN" I wouldn't have asked the question to begin with.

Comment: does this also apply on Visual Studio without msdn?

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo I have no idea, but I would not count on it.